# OpenCV's drawContours function crashes Android app

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to draw the largest contour detected by Imgproc.findContours in my Android app. Imgproc.findContours seems to find a bunch of contours but the code crashes when it tries to execute the Imgproc.drawContours function.

Here's the Java code:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(result, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_FLOODFILL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

largest_area = 0;
largest_contour_index = -1;

for(int i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++){
    double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));
    if(area > largest_area){
        largest_area = area;
        largest_contour_index = i;
    }
}

Mat contourDrawing = Mat.zeros(result.rows(), result.cols(),  CvType.CV_8UC3);

Log.d("contours.size()", Integer.toString(contours.size()));
Log.d("largest_area", Double.toString(largest_area));
Log.d("largest_contour_index", Integer.toString(largest_contour_index));

Imgproc.drawContours(contourDrawing, contours, largest_contour_index, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
```

Logcat output is as follows, showing that contours are detected:

D/contours.size(): 1901

D/largest_area: 343974.0

D/largest_contour_index: 825

But when it comes to drawing the contour using Imgproc.drawContours, the app crashes. I'm using OpenCV version 3.4.3. Does anyone know what might be wrong here? Thank you very much!

Here's the error log:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xb930b93 in tid 30396 (Thread-2), pid 30213

/lib/arm64/libopencv_java3.so (cv::drawContours(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, cv::_InputArray const&, int, cv::Point_<int>)+2124)

/lib/arm64/libopencv_java3.so (Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_drawContours_11+252)

/dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from ==/base.apk (deleted) (org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.drawContours+102)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure your Imgproc for Android works fine? What happens if you try other methods of that same package?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know Java but maybe I can kind of help?

suggestions:
1. what about using numpy's `zeros_like(image)` instead of taking in the rows and columns just to simplify things and reduce chances for errors there?

draw contours, in my experience, changes the image you draw on forever.  But you create an image just for the contours so you already know this...

**my guess at the problem:**

For your inputs into the `drawContours` function, your second parameter should be 'detected contours' from your `findContours`... I can't really tell but it looks like that might be `result` for you. Did you try using `result` in your contours parameters (in this case as `contours_to_draw`)?

in Python I use it like this:

```
cv.drawContours(copy__of_image, contours_to_draw, -1, color=desired_color, thickness=2)
```

the -1 is for drawing all the contours.  If you want to draw just some, you can draw the first or second and so on by changing this value, but if you know which contours you want to draw I would suggest passing them into contours_to_draw instead of using this parameter to determine which contours to draw. I guess you already knew all that too but it doesn't hurt to retell these things.

Does this help at all?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. `result` is the image that `findContours` takes as input. The detected contours are stored in `contours`.
In the code above, I tried to draw the largest contour on a new image. I also tried drawing the first or second contour but I get the same error...

Comment: Maybe instead of using the index to get your largest contour you can modify your code like this: `if(area > largest_area){largest_contour = contours.get(i)}` and when you call your `drawContours` function pass `largest_contour` as your contours and just draw all the contours? I don't know if it solves the problem but perhaps simplifying the code could eliminate the reason for the crashing.

Comment: That makes sense but it didn't work. I tried something like `Imgproc.drawContours(contourDrawing, contours.get(i), -1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);` but it expects the second parameter to be a list of contours, not just a single contour.

Comment: if you make the single contour a list then that should fix that particular problem! In python I'd do something like [largest_contour].  That turns a single contour into a list of one item.  Sorry I'm not able to help much :'(

Comment: No, it keeps crashing!
I had also tried creating a list as you said but unfortunately it doesn't seem to help.